# variable in brackets not recognised

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to write a script to search for a username using wildcard characters as per below.  The variable name must be included in brackets for the netapp commandlet to work - however the variable `$aduser` is not picked up from keyboard input and does not work - how do I get the `$aduser` wildcard variable picked up ?

Script prompts for an adusername e.g. `testy` and lists the groups user is a member of:

```
$aduser = Read-Host -Prompt 'Specify all or part of username: '
write-host

(Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like "*$aduser*"})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the filter in this way:

```
$aduser = Read-Host -Prompt 'Specify all or part of username: '
$aduser = "*$aduser*"
(Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $aduser})
```

Comment: Thanks Avshalom, didnt think to do that - works perfectly